# ElasticSearch indexing so query returns contains

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, contains

I've been trying to create my own index for users, where the query is indexed on the "name" value.

This is my current index settings:

```
{
   "users": {
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "analysis": {
               "filter": {
                  "shingle_filter": {
                     "max_shingle_size": "2",
                     "min_shingle_size": "2",
                     "output_unigrams": "true",
                     "type": "shingle"
                  },
                  "edgeNGram_filter": {
                     "type": "edgeNGram",
                     "min_gram": "1",
                     "max_gram": "20"
                  }
               },
               "analyzer": {
                  "autocomplete_query_analyzer": {
                     "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "lowercase"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  },
                  "autocomplete_index_analyzer": {
                     "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "lowercase",
                        "shingle_filter",
                        "edgeNGram_filter"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "number_of_replicas": "1"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and my mapping:

```
{
   "users": {
      "mappings": {
         "data": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "autocomplete_index_analyzer",
                  "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_query_analyzer"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Right now my problem is that search queries do not return results that contain the term. For example if I have a user "David", the search queries "Da", "Dav", "Davi", etc will return the value but search for "vid" or "avid" will not return any values.

Is this because of some value I'm missing in the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `nGram` instead of `edgeNGram`. So simply change this

```
              "edgeNGram_filter": {
                 "type": "edgeNGram",
                 "min_gram": "1",
                 "max_gram": "20"
              }
```

into this

```
              "edgeNGram_filter": {
                 "type": "nGram",             <--- change here
                 "min_gram": "1",
                 "max_gram": "20"
              }
```

Note that you need to wipe your index, recreate it and the populate it again.